# How to find bigram frequency on a RDD using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, bigdata

```
text_file = sc.textFile("/Users/xxx/Desktop/BigData/assign1/abc")
count1 = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) 
             .map(lambda x : (x,  1)) \
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

I am just taking this as an example. I have a huge dataset of 156215 entries

['This', 'is', 'my', 'room']
this returns me single word count.

If I need to find count of two words at a time.

['This is', 'is my', 'my room']

I have tried everything but it returns TypeError: PipelinedRDD issue.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this still operates by line; so if your file looks like

```
this is a test
what happens next
```

then `test what` does not get counted.

```
def word_pairs(line):
    words = line.split()
    return [a + " " + b for a,b in zip(words, words[1:])]

pairs = text_file.flatMap(word_pairs)
count = pairs.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Comment: What should be done to get test what as a one bigram which are on seperate lines?